# Making copy of table with data in Room Database

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I have a table which name is `CustomizedSelectionBean` and i  populate fields everywhere in an `Activity` working fine but I have a situation on `onBackpressed` of that `Activity` where the table is populated, a dialog is appear asked for "changes may not be saved if you press yes". if user press yes data is wiped out when cart has no items  and user go to Cart Screen but the situation is when user come to edit and do some customization but `onBackpressed` is pressed then user go through "yes" then all data is wiped but I have managed this on Boolean variable working fine but when a user  on edit mode user edit some data then it directly reflects to table data. So i want to make temp. or the copy of the table before any changes are made so that is I press back then get back that data.

I can do this by making another table and pasting all data to every single entity, But I'm in search of small solution.

Best approach should be, all data should be saved on the button "AddToCart" but I cannot do this because it will take very long time and affect the project.so just wanna go through small changes.

I have searched but no relevant solution have found yet.

Comment: I can understand what you try to achieve, but having either DB structure or some code that operates on the table would be helpful.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin can you explain it better so that I could implement it

Answer (score 0):

Use a draft mechanism maybe?

I think you should use a temporary table, with the same schema, and only merge it when the form gets validated.

You could also keep those in memory for later insertion.

Comment: Exactly this is I want, I need a way to merge all data to another table. I don't want to merge single-single item. at a time whole data should be merged.

Comment: Well I don't have your tables, but you just copy an imaginary `UserTable` as `UserDraftTable`, provide a Dao for it, fill it, and juste select its data and insert it in `UserTable` then. Simple inserts and selects.